# how to show toast according to the json response?

Tags: android, json, progressdialog

I am trying to show a toast according to the json result, so when the json result equal to 2 I want to show to the user that he should try again without leaving the current activity, but the app is forced to close when the json response is 2, here is my code:

```
class NewAccount extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Register.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Registering...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Creating product
         */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            String name = iname.getText().toString();
            String email = iemail.getText().toString();
            String reEmail = ireEmail.getText().toString();
            String password = ipassword.getText().toString();
            String rePassword = irePassword.getText().toString();
            String id = iid.getText().toString();
            String phone = iphone.getText().toString();
            String address1 = iaddress1.getText().toString();
            String address2 = iaddress2.getText().toString();

            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", id));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("phone", phone));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("address1", address1));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("address2", address2));
            System.out.print(name.length());
            // getting JSON Object
            // Note that create product url accepts POST method
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_register,
                    "POST", params);

            if(json != null) {

                // check log cat fro response
                Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

                // check for success tag
                try {
                    int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                    if (success == 1) {
                        // successfully created product
                        Intent i = new Intent(Register.this, MainPage.class);
                        startActivity(i);

                        // closing this screen
                        finish();
                    }
                    else if(success == 2){

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "kejfkjerfk", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        }
            }

            else{

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "An error occurred, please try again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            return null;
        }

/**
 * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
 * *
 */
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once done
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Please give us your JSON data and the exception.

Comment: in this case the JSON data is an array of 2 elements, `('success'=>2, 'message'=>'error')`

Comment: so this is what your program print at `Log.d("Create Response", ...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make a loop that will finish when success == 1:

```
while (true){
    ...
    if (success == 1) {
        // successfully created product
        Intent i = new Intent(Register.this, MainPage.class);
        startActivity(i);

        // closing this screen
        finish();
        break;
    }
    else if(success == 2){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "kejfkjerfk", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    ...
}
```